# How can I update a field with the same value in another object?

Tags: workflow

I am trying to create a workflow rule that will update my Account Customer Segmentation based on the Opportunity Level from the Opportunity Object, but when choosing the "Specify New Field Value," I am forced to update it to one of the picklist values, when I would rather use a formula so that the Account.Renewal Term is the same as the Opportunity.Opportunity Level.

They have the same pick list options.

Should I just make a different rule for each value of the picklist? (Only resulting in 4 workflow rules )

Or should I try to create an Apex Trigger ( I am new and not good at those )